# Creating an sliding input activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-xml

i am trying to create an activity for users to input data in an android application. Many inputfields are required and i therefore wanted to make them into multiple fullscreen scrollable pages. 
[Like this only with input fields in each slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjLGg.gif)

I have downloaded the code from this git: https://github.com/akrajilwar/Android-Intro-Slider-Screen, but i dont know how to put input fields in each of this views. As you can see in the git; each of the sliding pages are different xmls but they have no corresponding java files. All code is in a java file which has a viewPage in it.

I am struggeling to come up with any ideas on how to do this. I cant find something similar any place on the internet and need some advice for how to do this, either building on what they already have done in the git or something completely different.

Comment: That's a simple ViewPager with buttons to switch the view being displayed.  Read up some tutorials on how to use ViewPagers and come back with specific questions.

Comment: yeah i know, i guess my question is how should i go about adding interactive elements like input fields and buttons for those views?